# no module named 'pip' on windows while installing openpyxl

Tags: python, windows, installation, module, pip

I am install a third party module for the first time.

I am on python 3.10. I have download the `openpyxl` and extracted the zip folder into:

```
D:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib
```

Then I went to:

```
D:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

Typed `cmd` on the address bar and then typed `pip install openpyxl`.

This is the message returned:

```
D:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts>pip install openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Comment: you can try `python -m pip install <package>`

Comment: If my commend solved the problem, please make sure to accept is as solution! It may be helpful for other newcomers

Answer (score 1):

That's because `pip` is an Alias. The true command is indeed `pip3` (or `pip2` depending on what Python version you're using). For Ubuntu, there is an useful tool called python3-is-python which creates this alias. Try looking if this also exists for Windows!

Also, make sure you are running the `cmd` as administrator. It is very common for Windows to not be able to see those commands.

Comment: I am on windows and I have run cmd as admin. Still couldn't get pip install openpyxl or pip3 install openpyxl 

I had to do it manually, download and put into my Python directory, run cmd from where I have setup.py file in, and typed python setup.py install. This worked instead.

However I still want to resolve how can I install packages from cmd..